# Ubuntu WSL does not start default distro

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I switched computers and exported my Ubuntu WSL to use on the new one.
I followed the process [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) and set my imported distribution as default.

However, when I start my Ubuntu app (by clicking on the Ubuntu icon), it starts installing a new distribution. Is there something I am missing?  How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you import the tarball (.tar.gz file) to new PC then why you have installed Ubuntu from Windows store. Use `wsl.exe` directly to run that distro.

Comment: I like running the Ubuntu app instead. I had a lot of things configured in it. Is that not possible?